# Cloud function to deduct values from a user balance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud functions quite heavily in an app I'm building and wanted some advise how best to tackle this problem.

My function looks like this

```js
exports.deductFromBalance = functions.database.ref('listings{listing}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const author = snap.val().uid;
  return admin.database().ref(`balances/${snap.val().uid}`).update({
    balance: //current balance -= 1
  })
})
```

I need a way to reduce the balance by one each time a listing is successfully created. Is there a way for me to reduce this value without having to read the current value?

Comment: nope. you'd need an SQL server to do so. what's wrong with reading the value?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it to be honest, I'm just making sure I don't make any unnecessary reads to ensure the app runs as quickly as possible. Thanks for responding, If you post an answer, I'll mark it for you!

Comment: using a transaction is even better, eg. in case of simultaneous writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no atomic increment/decrement operations in the Firebase Realtime Database. You'll need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) to set the new value based on the current value atomically.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this is great!